# Removing items not present in the selected list

Tags: pandas, list, jupyter-notebook

I am solving a multilabel classification problem.
The dataset is in the format

```
| question | tags |
| ----- | ------- |
| How to print an array? | ['tag1' , 'tag2' , 'tag3'] |
| MathError: Cannot divide 0/0 | ['tag1' , 'tag6'] |
| Vertically align text to top within a UILabel | ['tag9', 'tag3'] |
```

I need to have like top 1000 tags only and remove all the rows which doesn't consist the tag. And, Also remove the tags from the tags column if it doesn't belong in the top 1000.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) first for convert lists to column, then get top tags by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and filter by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df.explode('tags')

top = df1['tags'].value_counts().index[:1000]
df2 = df1[df1['tags'].isin(top)].groupby('question')['tag'].agg(list).reset_index()
```

Comment: It works partially. The original tag list should only remove the non top 1000 tags and maintain its status quo.  I mean as in above if  tag3 isnt the top1000 tag then it should be removed but the row should be `| How to print an array? | ['tag1' , 'tag2' ] |`

Comment: the merged Questions has mixed ascii values with characters and isnt in original format.